# What's wrong with this Excel code involving IFs?

Tags: if-statement, sum, conditional-statements, excellibrary

```
=IF(B33=I33,K33,IF(B33=I34,K34,IF(B33=I35,K35)))*1000+(D33)/(C33)
```

The code works fine as this:

```
=IF(B33=I33,K33,IF(B33=I34,K34,IF(B33=I35,K35)))*1000+(D33)
```

But I want to afterwards divide the figure by the value in C33. I have tried multiple ways of including the `/ C33` but they all add up to the wrong value or give errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets are in the wrong place:

```
=(IF(B33=I33,K33,IF(B33=I34,K34,IF(B33=I35,K35)))*1000+D33)/C33
 ^                                                        ^
```

Key ones highlighted. Note that you will get errors if the value in `C33` is zero...

Comment: i tried 
"=IF(B33=I33,K33,IF(B33=I34,K34,IF(B33=I35,K35*1000+(D33))))/(C33)"
which worked for the thrid iF
but if i use the below it works al be it it looks messy

=IF(B33=I33,K33*1000+(D33),IF(B33=I34,K34*1000+(D33),IF(B33=I35,K35*1000+(D33))))/(C33)